# My docker-compose asp.net core project is not properly running, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a small `web service` that I wrote in `asp.net core 2.2`, Im using `docker-compose` for this project but I cant get it to work properly, everytime I try to run it I get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and it doesnt show my `Swagger` documentation. For now Im just using the self generated `docker file` from Visual Studio because I want to get at least my Swagger documentation so It doesnt show the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. 
When I do `docker ps` it shows the following:

[image]

So I know the container is up and running.

**My docker file:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY AppointmentsAPI/AppointmentsAPI.csproj AppointmentsAPI/
RUN dotnet restore AppointmentsAPI/AppointmentsAPI.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/AppointmentsAPI
RUN dotnet build AppointmentsAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish AppointmentsAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AppointmentsAPI.dll"]
```

**Docker-Compose file:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appointmentsapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}appointmentsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AppointmentsAPI/Dockerfile
```

As you guys can see everything is self generated by visual studio, so it should work, I only want to be able to see my documentation or at least have it working and after that I will add the other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding port 80 to Compose file. You are exposing port in dockerfile which will work with `docker run -p 80:80 ...`. Using compose you need to map the port.

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  appointmentsapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-appointmentsapi
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: AppointmentsAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

you can Map 80 to whatever you want or let docker map it for you.

Let Docker map external port:

```
ports: 
  - 80
```

Map port 80 to external 3000

```
ports:
  - 80:3000
```

**UPDATE:**

running VirtualBox and needed to use the VirtualBox IP rather than `localhost`.

Using the virtual box IP and adding port mapping to the compose file should resolve the issue.

Comment: can you run `docker run --rm -p 80:80 -d nginx`  then go to `localhost`

Comment: You should see page that says Welcome to MINX

Comment: This will tell us if the port is actually blocked or not, if the nginx container works then  port 80 is open and working

Comment: It does not show the MINX Welcome page, does that means the port 80:80 is blocked? what should I do?

Comment: did you get an error? if you Run `docker ps` ... do you see the NGINX container listed?

Comment: The container is running (nginx) but it doesnt show anything, it gives the same ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: okay try this, run the same command but replace `-p 80:80` with `-p 3000:3000` the go to `localhost:3000` should see this in browser:  http://35.163.173.239

Comment: It gives the same error, but the container its running in the port 3000 tcp

Comment: Okay most likely Jorge is right and there is Firewall/AntiVirus blocking access to the ports/network. Can you run `docker ps` and post post the info for the nginx container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189617/discussion-between-vindev-and-teler).

Answer (score 0):

the ports and the firewall, check it, because docker make a owns network

Comment: Turned off windows firewall and added the ports and its still giving the same error. :(